# How to Find WooCommerce Product without Featured Images

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets, wordpress-featured-image

I want that the products not showing on the shop frontend who are missing the featured image.

I did not found until now a good solution.
I want excluded these products.
Looking for a snippet code or an solution i can filter them on the backend, then i can delete.them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query to get products list which does not have featured image

```
add_shortcode('wp', 'remove_products_without_thumb');
function remove_products_without_thumb(){
if(isset($_REQUEST['delete'] == 'Delete')){
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        wp_trash_post( get_the_ID() );
        // Display product information here
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // No products found
}
}
}
```

Now you can use `yourdomain.com?delete=Delete` and hit in browser.

Comment: Thx for the quick responce. Where can I place this code? In snippet? And where I find the product list. Is it also possible to make the code that the products without image direct goes to the trash....and then i can delete them regular in Wordpress?

Comment: I updated code as per your request

Comment: Thx for your update, can you explain me where to put this code?

Comment: put this code in your functions.php file in theme

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. there is in two way.

1. Don’t add Thumbnail image when you adding Product item.
2. Add display none for Product Thumbnail wrapper. ;) Fastest way ;)

**Otherwise you can use hooks to remove Remove featured image from showing on product display page**
**To do this without editing any of the theme files, just add this to a plugin or functions.php in a child theme:**

add_filter  ('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html',

'remove_featured_image', 10, 3);

function remove_featured_image ($html, $attachment_id, $post_id) {

```
$featured_image = get_post_thumbnail_id ($post_id);


if  ($attachment_id != $featured_image)  {

     return $html;

 }

 return '';
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I want to remove the products that don't have an image.
Is there a code when they don't have an image that they are placed in the wordpress trash....if desired I can delete them there.